# Can't clone app from heroku - no access

Tags: heroku

I have a few heroku accounts, but I logged into one using account 1. I then tried to clone an app that belongs to that account, but the error I got references the email for a different account saying it doesn't have permissions.

I installed the heroku plugin for multiple accounts, but I'm still puzzled what is wrong

> C:\my_local>heroku accounts
>   jrub
>
> C:\my_local>heroku apps --account jrub
>   === My Apps
>   free-spi
>   learnhand
>   mob-surf
>   websck-tst
>
> C:\my_local>heroku git:clone -a mob-surf --account jrub
>   Cloning from app 'mob-surf'...
>   Cloning into 'mob-surf'...

```
!  Your account wbsuf@gmail.com does not have access to mob-surf.
! 
! SSH Key Fingerprint: ad:bb:4b:24:52:00:88:8d:66:70:32:8a:28:38:be:33

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```